# Summation. Combining different set of indices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am reading the second chapter of Concrete Mathematics book and I cant get my head aroud a simple concept: it is stated there that
$$
\sum _{k \in K} a_k + \sum _{k \in K'}a_k = \sum _{k \in K \cap K'}a_k + \sum _{k \in K \cup K'} a_k
$$

But how it is possible if $K \cap K' \in K \cup K'$ (intersection is a part of union).

Comment: Is $K'$ the complement of $K$? If so then $K\cap K'$ would be the null set. If not then the "double counting" occurs in both RHS and LHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because in the LHS you are counting the elements that appear in $K$ and $K'$ twice, so you must do the same in the RHS (one for $K\cup K'$ and another one for $K\cap K'$). On the other hand, the elements that appear only once (either in $K$ or $K'$, but never in both at the same time) are counted only once, in the sum with indices in $K\cup K'$.

To help you wrap your head around it, if $K  = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $K' = \{3,4,5,6\}$ you would get:
$$(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4) + (a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6) = (a_3 + a_4) + (a_1 + a_2  + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6)$$